# Microsoft Project 2010 - Is there any timesheet functionality available in this package

Tags: microsoft-project, project-management

I've started using Project 2007 to map out my workload.

I'm thinking about upgrading to 2010. What I would like to know is if there is any timesheet functionality in Project 2010 that would allow me to enter my actual working time on a task against what was planned?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Project server 2010 does, I'm not sure about project itself however

check out the live demo here

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9713654

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can enter actuals for a task but only on the cumulative level, not day by day.  If you do enter the cumulative work by task day by day then the program will record the hours against the right day and you can get them back out with a report.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little to explain exactly how to do this?